# Beam/Dataflow warning & zombie bucket in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a Beam/Dataflow pipeline (using Dataflow SDK 2.0.0-beta3 & running on GCP) that uses the template functionality. Whenever we run it, it always spits out the following warning:

```
11:05:30,484 0    [main] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.util.DefaultBucket - No staging location provided, attempting to use default bucket: dataflow-staging-us-central1-435085767562
11:05:31,930 1446 [main] WARN  org.apache.beam.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer - Request failed with code 409, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?predefinedAcl=projectPrivate&predefinedDefaultObjectAcl=projectPrivate&project=<redacted>"
```

However, we are setting the `--stagingLocation` parameter, and we can see all the binaries/jars etc. are uploaded to the bucket that we've specified in the `--stagingLocation` parameter.

However, Beam/Dataflow then creates the following zombie bucket in GCS in our project: `dataflow-staging-us-central1-435085767562`

Why is this happening if we are clearly setting the `--stagingLocation` parameter?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the command you used to create the template pipeline? Did you specify --stagingLocation when you created it? And what command are you using to launch the pipeline? I'm just trying to understand which commands you are referring to when setting stagingLocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is [BEAM-2143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2143). Specifically, althhough the error says you need to specify `--stagingLocation`, you actually need to specify `--tempLocation`.